# ReadAllText returning wrong value

Tags: c#, string, csv

I'm trying to read in a text file , taking only every fifth word and then going to a new line , Thanks to the feedback from my previous questions my code now looks like this

```
               string fileText =  File.ReadAllText(ofd.FileName).Replace(Environment.NewLine, ",");

               string[] lines = new string[]
                {
                    File.ReadAllText(ofd.FileName)
                };

               var fifthOnEachLine = lines.Select(x => x.Split(',')[4]);
                   objSqlCommands.sqlCommandInsertorUpdate2("INSERT",  fifthOnEachLine);//laClient[0]);
```

However when I run the code the data I get back looks like this :

```
        System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectArrayIterator`2[System.String,System.String]
```

does anyone know how to fix this ?

Comment: Use `ToList()` to execute iterator

Comment: Variable `fifthOnEachLine` is of type System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectArrayIterator`2[System.String,System.String] and you see its .ToString() represenation but it is basically IEnumerable, so you have to iterate the results.

Answer (score 0):

You must iterate over your query result, executing command for each item in result, like this:

```
foreach(var item in File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName).Select(x => x.Split(',')[4]));
{
    objSqlCommands.sqlCommandInsertorUpdate2("INSERT",  item);
}
```

**BTW**, for some reason you're using **File.ReadAllText()**, which returns string for all file content. Most likely, you will need to use **File.ReadAllLines()**, which will return string for each line in your file.

Comment: added this code in and it still doesnt return the correct data just the  System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectArrayIterator`2[System.String,System.String]

Comment: Slightly modified code. What shows your debugger on foreach iteration? If you will receive something like "OutOfRangeException", it means, that there is no way to split your line to 5 words.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Dmitriy it should be

```
List<String> words=File.ReadAllLines(path)
                       .Select(x=>if(Regex.Split(x,"\s+").Length>=5)Regex.Split(x,"\s+")[4])
                       .ToList();
```

Comment: using this I'm told the index is out of bounds of the array